# Disable failover in HaProxy

Tags: haproxy

I would like to have two (or more) jetty servers behind a HaProxy that is sticky on JSESSION. I would however like to disable failover, such that clients are not moved from Server1 to Server2 in the case Server1 is down. But I cannot find such a configuration option when searching http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.4/configuration.html. Is it possible?

For good measure, my motivation for disabling failover is because the state between client and server is quite complicated and long lived. HaProxy's job is to distribute clients over multiple servers and keep them there for as long as the jetty session is valid.

If another load balancer is capable of JSESSION sticking without failover, then I'm interested.

Answer (score 0):

I’m fairly certain using `no option redispatch` on your backend will keep the connections stuck to the failed server from being sent to the still active one.

Comment: Thank you, for the great suggestion. Looks like what I need. I was going down a path of ACL where i could match the session in the stick table and see if the corresponding server was healthy, then redirecting clients to a static error page or sending a specific error code. But this would be much much cleaner. I'll accept this answer once I've tested it :)